# Error: Must use import to load ES Module en proyecto node-typescript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, npm, yarn

Se que hay varias preguntas sobre el mismo error, pero no he logrado resolverlo con ninguna,
se supone que aparece cuando se está intentando importar una libreria con `const express = require("express")`, pero en ningun lado de mi codigo estoy importando alguna libreria de esa forma.

Lo estaba haciendo antes con la libreria 'dotenv' pero ya la removi, igualmente elimine la carpeta `node_modules` y el archivo `yarn.lock` y aún sigue apareciendo cuando ejecuto de nuevo `yarn` para instalar dependencias e intento ejecutar `yarn dev`.

Este es el contenido de mi arhcivo package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "auth app example using node",
  "main": "app.ts",
  "author": "robert",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^11.4.1",
    "argon2": "^0.31.0",
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.5",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "pino": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/config": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.197",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.9",
    "pino-pretty": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  }
}
```

Y mi archivo tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
  
      /* Projects */
      // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
      // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
      // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
      // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
      // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
      // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
  
      /* Language and Environment */
      "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
      // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
      // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
      "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */,
      // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
      // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
      // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
      // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
      // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
      // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
  
      /* Modules */
      "module": "ES6" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
      // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
      "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
      // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
      // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
      // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
      // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
      // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
      // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
      // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
      // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
  
      /* JavaScript Support */
      // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
      // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
      // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */
  
      /* Emit */
      // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
      // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
      // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
      // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
      // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
      // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
      // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
      // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
      // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
      // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
      // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
      // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
      // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
      // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
      // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
      // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
      // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
      // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
      // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
      // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
      // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
      // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
      // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
  
      /* Interop Constraints */
      // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
      // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
      "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
      // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
  
      /* Type Checking */
      "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
      // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
      // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
      // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
      // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */,
      // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
      // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
      // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
      // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
      // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
      // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
      // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
      // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
      // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
      // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
      // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
      // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
      // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
  
      /* Completeness */
      // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
      "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    }
  }
```

Este es el error completo:

```
[INFO] 21:57:54 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.2.2)
Compilation error in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\src\app.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\src\app.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\src\app.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-200610689935671.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-200610689935671.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-200610689935671.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
[ERROR] 21:57:54 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Coding projects\expressJs\node-auth\src\app.ts
```

Y por ultimo mi punto de entrada, el archivo `app.ts`

```
import express from 'express';
import config from "config"
import connectToMongo from './utils/connect';
import log from './utils/logger';
import router from './routes';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(router);

const port = config.get("port") ||  3001;

app.listen(port, () => {
    log.info(`Server listing at http://localhost:${port}`);

    connectToMongo();

});
```

La unica manera de resolver el error es usar "commonJS" tanto en package.json como en tsconfig.json y borrar el uso de la dependencia que require de type="module", en mi caso es "nanoid", esta libreria en sus ultimas versiones se paso por completo al estandar type="module", por lo que no se puede usar teniendo configurado type="commonJs"

Sin embargo esto aún no resulve el problema

Comment: vos no estas importando de esa forma, pero quizas alguno de tus modulos si, que pasa si eliminas el type='module' de tu package.json?

Comment: Aparece el error:

"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Igual tengo un error en la pregunta, no es 'import _ from _; se supone que es cuando teniendo el type="module" e intento importar de manera "const _ = require()" (commonJs). ya modifico la pregunta y añado el error completo

Comment: El error  "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" sucede con la libreria "express"

Comment: La libreria "ts-node-dev" exporta una función a la manera commonJs, podría ser eso? "module.exports.registerExtensions = registerExtensions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una forma de solucioar el error, incluye evitar el uso de `type="module"` y en su lugar usar `"commonJs"`.
Esto en mi caso hará que una libreria `nanoid` me dé problemas porque en sus versiones más recientes (4.0 en mi caso) eliminaron por completo la capacidad de usarla con `"commonJS"` `(const nanoid = require("nanoid"))`

La desinstalé e instalé una versión anterior que sí soporta "commonJs":

```
yarn add nanoid@^3.0.0
```

Una vez hecho eso la app arranca correctamente.